# Java Scripting - ClassCastException

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с этой ошибкой: `java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast jdk.internal.dynalink.beans.StaticClass to me.catcoder.jsgui.ClickHandler`
Сама ошибка выскакивает при выполнении метода `addClickHandler`. Вот сам код:

```
var ClickHandler = ClickHandlerClass.static;

function fill(){

var handler = Java.extend(ClickHandler, {

    click: function(type, player) {

        print("Click");
    }
});
print(handler);

inventory.addClickHandler(10, handler); //здесь
```

}